"Pressure" due to gravitational compression in a uniform sphere
I was trying to solve the following problem from the book Problems in General Physics by I.E. Irodov:
1.216: A uniform sphere has a mass M and radius R. Find the pressure p inside the sphere, caused by gravitational compression, as a function of the distance r from its centre. Thus find the pressure at the centre of the earth, assuming it to be uniform.
The answer given in the book is $$p=\frac{3GM^2}{8{\pi}R^4}\left(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)$$
Here $G$ is the Gravitational constant.
The answer given for the second part (pressure at the centre of the earth) is $1.8\times 10^6 atm$
My questions:

Why is the force per unit area inside the sphere referred to as pressure? It is called by that name in several other places as well, and nowhere is it called a stress, as I expected it should be if the sphere is made of a solid.

If it is called pressure, I think it is implied that it is isotropic, i.e. the same in all directions. How can we prove that?


If we assume beforehand that it is indeed a pressure and is isotropic, I was able to prove the result given in the book, but I could not understand how we can reach those assumptions.

You are assume a fluid. At those sorts of pressure  cohesive stresses are ngligible and  even solids flow.

Please show how you obtained the result with the given assumptions.

First, I will do a quick derivation of your pressure equation to demonstrate that it depends on the assumption of constant density. The significance of this assumption to the question will be explained in the text below the line lower down, if you want to skip the derivation.
Consider a solid sphere of radius r that encloses a mass of $M_r$, where r is less than the radius (R) of the Earth (R). This enclosed mass is the mass that provides the gravitational attraction on any mass at radius r. On the surface of this internal sphere is a thin spherical shell of mass $m_r$ and infinitesimal thickness $dr$. The force ($F_r$) exerted on the surface of the internal sphere by this thin shell is:
$$F_r = \frac{G M_r m_r}{r^2} \tag{1}$$
Since force is equal to pressure (P) multiplied by area, we can write the above equation as;
$$4 \pi r^2 dP = \frac{G M_r m_r}{r^2},\tag{2}$$
where $4 \pi r^2$ is the surface area of the interior shell with radius r. If the density ($\rho$) is uniform we can write the mass of the internal sphere as $M_r =  4/3 \pi r^3 \ \rho$ where $\rho$ is the density of the Earth $\rho = \frac{M}{4/3\pi R^3}$ and $m_r$ and the mass of the thin shell with radius r as $m_r = 4 \pi r^2 dr \ \rho$ to give us:
$$4 \pi r^2 dP = \frac{G (4/3 \pi r^3 \rho) (4 \pi r^2  \rho\ dr)}{r^2}$$
$$\rightarrow dP = 4/3 \ G \pi \rho^2  r \ dr, \tag{3}$$
This is the pressure due to the thin shell. To obtain the total pressure acting on the inferior sphere we have to sum up the contribution due to all the shells all the way back up to the surface so we have to integrate from r to R:
$$\rightarrow \int^0_{P_r} dP = \int^R_r 4/3 \ G \pi \rho^2  r \ dr,$$
$$\rightarrow -P_r = 2/3 \ G \pi \rho^2  (R^2 - r^2) ,\tag{4}$$
If we replace $\rho$ with $\frac{M}{4/3 \pi R^3}$ we obtain the equation in the OP:
$$2/3 \ G \pi \left(\frac{M}{4/3 \pi R^3}\right)^2  (R^2 - r^2) = \frac{3GM^2}{8\pi R^4}  \left(1 - \frac{r^2}{R^2}\right) .\tag{5}$$


If it is called pressure, I think it is implied that it is isotropic,
i.e. the same in all directions. How can we prove that?

The important thing to note is that the derivation required we assume uniform density. If $\rho$ was a function of r, we would have obtained a different result. If the material the Earth was made from was compressible we would expect the density to increase with depth. This means the material is assumed to be incompressible and this in turn implies the material behaves like an incompressible fluid. It is the nature of an incompressible material to have isotropic pressure. Consider some compressible material like expanded polystyrene foam. When you stand on it you leave foot-shaped imprints and the foam in the footprints is compressed and has a higher density than the surrounding material. This suggests a compressible material can vary in density and have directional pressure. Now consider a plastic bag filled with water. If you squash the bag vertically its horizontal dimension gets larger to keep the volume constant because water can be consider incompressible for practical purposes. If a material cannot be compressed it means its density and volume have to remain constant under pressure. Now consider a block of incompressible material that initially has uniform pressures in all directions. If we concentrate on a sub cell of the material and increase the pressure on the cell in the vertical y direction it deforms slightly so that the height of the cell is slightly reduced, in order to maintain its volume and density (which is what it means to be incompressible) the cell has to expand in the horizontal direction to compensate and in doing so the cell increases the horizontal pressure on its neighbours which equalises the pressure in all directions. Note that incompressible does not mean the material cannot be deformed.

Why is the force per unit area inside the sphere referred to as
pressure? It is called by that name in several other places as well,
and nowhere is it called a stress, as I expected it should be if the
sphere is made of a solid.

As Mike Stone mentioned in the comments, a solid can behave like a fluid under great pressures (and temperatures). It can be noted that in the case of the Earth, the rock in the mantle literally is a fluid called magma (or lava when it comes to the surface). Nearer the surface, large parts of the Earth consists of soil with air gaps between the particles. Soil in not incompressible, because the air gaps can be collapsed under pressure. For this reason (and others) the equation cannot be considered an exact model of the pressure inside the Earth. Another reason is that heavy elements tend to accumulate at the centre of the Earth due to buoyancy effects and so the density of the Earth is not uniform.

We can make a slightly improved model, if we know the average density in each region and calculate the pressure of the concentric shells using their assumed regional densities and then adding them all together.
A different formula is required to calculate the internal pressures of a star because the gas it is composed of is compressible, while incompressibility is a crucial assumption for the formula in the OP.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/442747/123208 has info on the variation of density with depth. Also see http://www.typnet.net/Essays/EarthGrav.htm & the external links at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preliminary_reference_Earth_model

Hi @PM2Ring I was just trying to make the point that the formula in the OP has an assumption of uniform constant density built in, but I quite happily accept that in reality, that is not generally true. Thanks for the info!

Sure, the OP has an assumption of uniform constant density. I just added those links for anyone who wants to take the trouble to do a more accurate calculation.

I appreciate you answering in such detail. Thank you so much. But I have two questions: 1. The force on the spherical shell element shoukd be zero since force is a vector. We will have to take another element like a hemispherical shell for ex. 2. Is there a math proof for the assertion that any incompressible material shows isotropic pressure?

Consider a cylinder with gas trapped between two end pistons, each with area $2m^3$. Now apply a force of 10 N inwards at each end to compress the trapped gas. The pressure in the cylinder is now $20/4 = 5 Pa$. Note that  it is not zero despite the fact the force vectors at each end are acting in opposite directions. Individually each piston now has a gas  pressure of $5 Pa$ acting outwards on a surface are of $ 2 m^2$ so the outward force is 10 N balanc9ing the 10 N that is being applies inwards from the outside, so everything is in equilibrium.

I am not aware of a formal "proof for the assertion that any incompressible material shows isotropic pressure". I only have my argument that if we assume no material is infinitely rigid (proven to be true by special relativity) and if the material is incompressible (volume and density remains constant when pressure is applied), then any deformation of the material due to a force in one direction must result in the material deforming in another direction until the pressures are equalised in all directions in order to maintain the constant volume.

One property that defines a fluid is that it deforms to fill the cavity it is contained in. Imagine a single cylindrical concrete pillar that supports the ceiling of a large cavity. If enough pressure is applied  to the ceiling, the pillar will fail catastrophically into a pile of rubble. If we continue applying downward pressure the rubble will turn into dust. If we continue again, the dust will be squeezed into any remaining gaps. With enough pressure any solid starts behaving like a fluid.  Also as mentioned before, a lot of the material inside the Earth is a fluid of molten magma.

"1. The force on the spherical shell element should be zero since force is a vector." It might help to know that while force is a vector, pressure is defined as a scalar field.

I need a mathematical proof.
